# Does LinkedIn Rest API support Groups?

Tags: linkedin-api

I have managed to successfully post profile status updates and company status updates, but is it possible to use their API to send group updates?

I've seen some references to their Partner Program and I suspect that I might need to join that in order to unlock more of their API, however, this is currently unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  Access to Group posting API calls requires a partnership to help reduce abuse of the API.

You can apply for partnership with LinkedIn here:  https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Justin.  Unfortunately I requested this partnership but was told by LinkedIn that it wasn't required for what I needed.  Given what you have said this is not actually true, would you recommend that I retry the request?